# Stale code being run by android studio?

Tags: android

I had code to display a 'toast' in android with the text 'Text updated'. I then removed that code, and clicked run again, and this 'toast' still pops up. Could Android Studio be using old code? What is going on here?

Comment: Can you do a Build-> Clean and see?

Comment: I have restarted AS if that is the same thing?

Comment: No it is not the same,

Comment: Ok I will give this a go now

Comment: Yes even after the rebuild

Comment: Hmm... I am guessing that you are still having a toast somewhere in your code, If you are so sure about it, Uninstall the application from your device and run the application again

Comment: post the code..I guess some coding error..

Comment: I am sure I don't because I have removed all the imports and am getting no error

Comment: @Daniel did you uninstall your debug application from your test device and re run it?

Answer (score -1):

Clean the project and rebuild it.To clean the project go to *Build->Clean Project*

Sometimes the file system does not gets refreshed.

Comment: Even after the rebuild it does this.